# Scraping URLs from wikipedia in R yielding only half the URL

Tags: html, r, url, web, scrape

I am currently trying to extract the URLs from the wikipedia page with a list of chief executive officers, the code then opens the URLs and copies the text into .txt files for me to use. the trouble is the `allurls` object only contains the later half of the URL. For example `allurls[1]` gives **""/wiki/Pierre_Nanterme""**. Thus when I run this code

```
library("xml2")
library("rvest")

url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chief_executive_officers"

allurls <- url %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(2) a") %>% 
html_attr("href") %>% 
  .[!duplicated(.)]%>%lapply(function(x) 
read_html(x)%>%html_nodes("body"))%>%  
  Map(function(x,y) 
write_html(x,tempfile(y,fileext=".txt"),options="format"),.,
      c(paste("tmp",1:length(.))))

allurls[1]
```

I get the following error:

> Error: '/wiki/Pierre_Nanterme' does not exist.

Comment: You need to add `https://en.wikipedia.org` in front of that.

Comment: Yeah but how can I add that infront of all 179 entries? And in the middle of the code? I've tried making a new object but I can't workout how to add text infront of allurls[1]

Comment: At the `read_html` line: `read_html(paste0("https://en.wikipedia.org",x))%>%html_nodes("body"))%>%  `. That being said you need to either indent your piping or not pipe at all for clarity. Also, your scraped html_attr contains an incorrect element starting with `https`

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you, that solved that! Now the only error seems to come from the incorrect element you pointed out